# Want to select multiple Columns but group By only 1 Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I having total 4 columns in `Select` query. **Year**, **Net Value**, **Development Cost** & **Maintenance Cost**. From these 4 columns **Net Value** & **Development Cost** is calculated using `SUM()` method but **Maintenance Cost** is calculated using `Select Case` logic. I need it to `Group By` by **Year** only. But while executing, it is reading the `Select Case` column as well as exception as it is not included in `Group By` clause. How should I `Group By` only via Year? Below is my query:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(a.ProjectStartDate) AS [Year],
    '' AS 'NetValue',
    CEILING(SUM(CAST(a.DevEffortHours AS DECIMAL(18,2)) * @InternalRate)) AS 'DevelopmentCost',
    CEILING(CEILING(SUM(CAST(a.DevEffortHours AS DECIMAL(18,2)) * @InternalRate)) * @InternalRate * r.rate) AS 'MaintenanceCost'
FROM WREF_WIPTrackerKAIMainEntry a
INNER JOIN WREF_WIPTrackerKaiProductMaster b ON b.ID = a.KAIProjectID
INNER JOIN WREF_WIPTrackerStatusMaster c ON c.ID = a.StatusID
INNER JOIN WREF_WIPTrackerProductLifeMaster d ON d.ID = a.ProductLifeID
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT rate = CASE WHEN d.LifeType = '2-3 years' THEN 2.5
                       WHEN d.LifeType = '5 years' THEN 5
                       ELSE 1
                  END
) r
WHERE c.StatusType = 'Live'
GROUP BY YEAR(a.ProjectStartDate)
```

**Tried :** Group By using 1st column as **YEAR** `Required as it is`.

**Expected :** to get the results while grouping **YEAR**.

**Actually Resulted :** error message

> TableTrackerProductLifeMaster.LifeType is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or Group By clause.

Comment: Each year will (most probably) have different d.LifeType values. How do _you_ want to present their MaintenanceCosts?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Comment: Move your case inside your sum

Comment: Would wrapping the `CASE` expression inside a `SUM()` give you your desired results? Something like `CEILING(SUM(CASE ... END)) AS MaintenanceCost`.  EDIT: And perhaps  remove the `CEILING(SUM(...))` from inside the CASE. The CASE expression would then calculate the individual MaintenanceCost values which would then be summed.

Comment: @DaleK Honestly I never understand this question. Of all the error messages in SQL Server this is one of the clearest.

Comment: @Charlieface I know, but I think a lot of people new to SQL don't have a concept of sets and grouping etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the case expression is only to determine the rate `2.5` or `5` or `1`

```
CASE  WHEN d.LifeType = '2-3 years' 
      then CEILING(CEILING(SUM(cast(a.DevEffortHours as decimal(18,2)) * @InternalRate)) * @InternalRate * 2.5)
      WHEN d.LifeType = '5 years' 
      then CEILING(CEILING(SUM(cast(a.DevEffortHours as decimal(18,2)) * @InternalRate)) * @InternalRate * 5)
      Else CEILING(CEILING(SUM(cast(a.DevEffortHours as decimal(18,2)) * @InternalRate)) * @InternalRate * 1) 
      END
```

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` to perform the evaluation

```
CROSS APPLY
(
    select rate = CASE  WHEN d.LifeType = '2-3 years' 
                        THEN 2.5
                        WHEN d.LifeType = '5 years' 
                        THEN 5
                        ELSE 1
                        END
) r
```

And then change that case expression to simply

```
CEILING(CEILING(SUM(cast(a.DevEffortHours as decimal(18,2)) * @InternalRate * @InternalRate * r.rate))) AS MaintenanceCost
```

Comment: I have modified my query above as per your suggestion, after executing it's giving me error as `Column 'r.rate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: the `r.rate` should be within the `SUM()`